# IE Expected identifier, string or number (not a comma!)

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I am getting this error for some weird reason, it just keeps appearing and i cant seem to understand whats wrong with it. I am using EXT js and Symfony2.

Following is the code in the twig file:

```
var portalInitialState = {{ base_macros.generateState( designer_state  ) }};
    </script>
```

Which converts to:

```
var portalInitialState = [];
    </script>
```

At this line i get the error in IE8, i cant seem to understand whats wrong with this, if i run this code in ie console, it works fine. Can somebody shade some light on this matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the previous line in the code.

"Expected Identifier" generally means that it found something, but was expecting something else. If the error is on line 5, then it is possible that line 4 isn't terminated properly.

For example:

```
var x = 1,
var y = [];
```

will create an error, but the following two examples will work fine:

```
var x = 1;
var y = [];
```

or

```
var x = 1,
y = [];
```